# "describe your changes" text field not taking any text in my apptivate app

Tags: support, apptivate.ms

I have submitted my app on Apptivate for contest. when I try to edit the app and write any text in "describe your changes" and tries to save it display "nothing has changed" while I have entered the text in "describe your changes" text field. Please let me know is it bug or what?

Comment: I think that "describe your changes" should describe what you changed like describing edit to a post. You should change things like "Name of the app", "Name of the app's logo", "Category" etc.

Comment: I thought it is like what are the changes you have done while porting the app from iOS, Android to Windows.

Comment: may be I am wrong.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Is right. "Describe your changes" is a summary of what you've changed when making an edit (it'll be automatically set to something like "modified screenshots" etc. if unset).

Comment: @balpha cheers, since I didn't submit anything can't edit to verify. Will post answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "describe your changes" field should describe what you changed, same way like describing edit to a post.

You should change things like "Name of the app", "Name of the app's logo", "Category" etc then describe what you changed. Note it's optional, if left blank the system will fill it by itself to something like "modified screenshots" etc. (again, same like edits)

Comment: ok, thanks for letting me know, I am assuming it something else.

Answer (score 3):

I'm changing the field description from "Describe your changes" to "Edit summary", to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, I have written a blog for that http://technicalblogspotarea.blogspot.in/2013/06/apptivate-prompt-changes.html